# Sublime Text 2 Comment Format Support

Tags: plugins, comments, sublimetext, docblocks

Does Sublime Text 2 can support the comment like this ?

```
/** @param @return */
```

Does any plugin can do it in `PHP` or `JS` or `CSS`?
(I do install the plugin :`DocBlockr` already.
But it can't work in windows7 now)

[image]

[image]

[Additional post on segmentfault.com](http://segmentfault.com/q/1010000000095881) (in Chinese)

Add below :2013-8-18 20:54:11
the image（found from a video,But i'm looking for this plugin either）  use the `PHP`,Both the DocBlockr can't work on my PC
environment：

```
win7 64bit
python2.7
sublime text 2221
```

Comment: what is the program you were using in the images? And what kind of functionality are you looking for in the docblocks - just autocompletion, or automatic generation of the docblock, or what?

Comment: also, for what it's worth, I can't get DocBlockr to work on OSX or Win7 - at least the function where you type `/**` on the line just about a function definition, and it autocompletes the various values. I just updated [this issue](https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs/issues/209) so hopefully someone will fix it soon.

Comment: Hey @MattDMo, author of docblockr here. Curious why it's not working for you. Drop me a line here or on the github issues page.

Comment: @nickf - thanks for the note, but docblockr seems to be working just fine for me now, on Windows and OS X. Thanks for the great plugin!

Answer (score 0):

the image（found from a video,But i'm looking for this plugin either） use the PHP,Both the DocBlockr can't work on my PC